# Unable to reproduce result obtained from hyperparameter tuning using hyperopt

Tags: pytorch, random-seed, seeding, reproducible-research, hyperopt

I have built a Pytorch model and performed hyperparameters tuning using library Hyperopt. The result obtained is not reproducible despite I have already call the below seeding function at the beginning of each run:

**util.py**

```
def seed_everything(seed=42):
    random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
```

**Trainer.py**

```
    def train(self, params):
        util.seed_everything()
        #wrote my training code here
```

Upon futher inspection, I have found that the **first** result of hyperopt tuning is always reproducible, but the subsequent runs are not. This is unexpected for me as I have already called *seed_everthing()* at the beginning of the train function.

In addition, if I run the training as below:

```
    for i in range(2):
        print ("in iteration ", i)
        trainer = Trainer(**configs)
        trainer.train(params)
```

The result of iteration 1 and 2 is different to each other, but they are always the same(i.e. iteration 1 always gives train_loss of 1.31714 while iteration 2 always gives 4.31235)

I am hoping that iteration 1 and iteration 2 would gives the same result since it should be reproducible.

Comment: Just a sanity check: When you did hyperopt, did you rebuild model from scratch each iteration (or continued training the same model)? Similarly, after hyperopt tuning, did you rebuild model each iteration?